# Inserting Entry values in Sqlite3 database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, user-interface, tkinter

I am creating a currency converter as a part of my college project using tkinter. I am new to GUI in python. I am trying to insert the values entered by user in entry (here e1) into the table of my **sqlite3** database (here con), but I just can't get it to work even after doing it in the way they showed it in the tutorials. I am getting an error that *Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.* It seems like I am missing something important. Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks!

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect("datavalues.db")
c=conn.cursor()

root=tk.Tk()
tkvar=StringVar(root)
tkvar2=StringVar(root)
convertfrom={'USD', 'INR', 'YEN', 'Pound Sterling', 'CAD'}
tkvar.set('INR')
convertto={'USD', 'INR', 'YEN', 'Pound Sterling', 'CAD'}
tkvar2.set('USD')

class body(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master=master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Currency Converter")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        self.e1=tk.Entry(self)
        self.e2=tk.Entry(self)
        self.b1=tk.Button(self, text="Convert", command=self.data_entry)
        self.b1.pack()
        self.e1.pack()
        self.e2.pack()
        self.a=self.e1.get()
        self.e1.place(x=100,y=1)
        self.e2.place(x=100,y=100)
        popupmenu=OptionMenu(self,tkvar, *convertfrom)
        popupmenu2=OptionMenu(self,tkvar2,*convertto)
        popupmenu.place(x=2,y=1)
        popupmenu2.place(x=2,y=100)
        self.b1.place(x=150,y=150)

    def data_entry(self): #ERROR IN THIS FUNCTION
        c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS con(unix REAL)")
        c.execute("INSERT INTO con (unix) VALUES(?)",(self.a)) 
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

root.geometry("400x300")
app=body(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably due to `self.a` being empty. Simply move the line that sets self.a into the `data_entry(self)` method prior to the SQL execution. This way, the entry will be read every time the button is pressed. But you should probably put a try block there to make sure self.a is not empty.

```
def data_entry(self): #ERROR IN THIS FUNCTION
    self.a = self.e1.get()
    if len(self.a):
        c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS con(unix REAL)")
        c.execute("INSERT INTO con (unix) VALUES(?)",(self.a)) 
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
     else:
        print("Error, entry has no content")
```